# Type mismatch: 'range'

Tags: excel, vbscript, scripting, automation, vba

I am writing VB script to insert the images from directory to Excel file with caption to images.

While I am running below code I am getting the error :

---

### Error

Script: C:\Users\user\Desktop\asd.vbs

Line:   7

Char:   13

Error:  Type mismatch: 'range'

Code:   800A000D

Source:     Microsoft VBScript runtime error

**Code :-**

```
set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
set objWorkbook=objExcel.workbooks.add()
With objExcel.ActiveSheet.Pictures.insert("C:\Users\user\Desktop\test\IMG_9717.JPG")
        .Left = range("A").Left
        .Top = range("A").Top
        .Height = range("A").RowHeight
        .Placement = xlMoveAndSize
End With
objWorkbook.Saveas "c:\testXLS1.xls"
objWorkbook.Close
objExcel.workbooks.close
objExcel.quit
set objExcel = nothing
```

Please guide me on above error. How can I fix this ?

Comment: Do you need to specify a complete cell reference e.g. A1?

Answer (score 1):

`VBScript` doesn't know what `Range` means.  If this was `VBA`, then it would refer directly to the `ActiveSheet` of the `Application` object.

You would need to qualify it properly with the application and sheet references (and as others have said, provide a full cell reference as well):

```
objExcel.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Left
```

...etc

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying for a complete cell reference rather than just the column e.g.

```
Range("A1").RowHeight
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
Range("A")
```

with:

```
Range("A1")
```

*there may be other errors*

Answer (score 0):

I tried below code. Its working fine. 
While using the range() function in VBS, we have to use it with Active Workbook. Check the below code.

```
set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
set objWorkbook=objExcel.workbooks.add()

set objsheet=objWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

Set objPic = objExcel.ActiveSheet.Pictures.insert("C:\Users\user\Desktop\test\IMG_9717.JPG")

With objPic
        .Left = objsheet.range("D3").Left
        .Top = objsheet.range("D3").Top
        .Height = objsheet.range("D3").RowHeight
End With

objWorkbook.Saveas "c:\testXLS1.xls"
objWorkbook.Close
objExcel.workbooks.close
objExcel.quit
set objExcel = nothing
```